# Jenkins marking build as success even the shell script has failed

Tags: shell, jenkins

[image]I have a shell script which download code from SVN and install it on to the server using this shell script. I am using SSH plugin(Build ENV step) to create login onto the server and run the script. This script generates output with return code and log file name generated, I have read the log file into a variable and cat it.

But my Jenkins job is getting success even if script returns return code other than zero. I believe this is because of the steps that I am doing after running the script.

Please let me know how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you post some of your code from your script and Jenkins job so we can see what's happening.

Otherwise, I'd consult [this answer on how Jenkins handles exit codes.](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/01/19/converting-conditional-to-pipeline/)

Comment: I have added image. Please let me know if that helps.